# What are the options for integration testing of React + Webpack + Rails API site?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, rest, webpack, integration-testing

Consider a site where Rails is used only for API. No server-side rendering.

With server-side rendering it's more or less clear. `capybara` starts `puma`, after which tests can connect to `puma` for pages.

But with no server-side rendering, there's no `puma` to ask for pages. How do I do that?

**Explain** yourself when downvoting, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Server-Side Rendering must be very common these days, I decided to [take](https://www.javascriptstuff.com/server-side-render/) an [alternative](https://malloc.fi/performance-cost-of-server-side-rendered-react-node-js) [approach](https://owais.lone.pw/blog/modern-frontends-with-django/).

Add the following gems to the `Gemfile`:

```rb
gem 'httparty', '~> 0.16.2'
gem 'childprocess', '~> 0.7.0'
```

Move the following lines from `config/environments/production.rb` to `config/application.rb` to make `RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT` available in the test environment.

```rb
if ENV['RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT'].present?
  config.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
end
```

Regarding `webpack`, make sure `publicPath` is set to `http://localhost:7777/`, and `UglifyJsPlugin` is not used in the [test](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/6479) [environment](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/v4.0.0/src/index.js#L9-L27).

And add these two files:

`test/application_system_test_case.rb`:

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

require 'uri'
require 'test_helper'
require 'front-end-server'

FRONT_END = ENV.fetch('FRONT_END', 'separate_process')
FRONT_END_PORT = 7777

Capybara.server_port = 7778
Capybara.run_server = ENV.fetch('BACK_END', 'separate_process') == 'separate_thread'
require 'action_dispatch/system_test_case'   # force registering and setting server
Capybara.register_server :rails_puma do |app, port, host|
  Rack::Handler::Puma.run(app, Port: port, Threads: "0:1",
    Verbose: ENV.key?('BACK_END_LOG'))
end
Capybara.server = :rails_puma

DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation

class ApplicationSystemTestCase < ActionDispatch::SystemTestCase
  driven_by :selenium, using: :chrome, screen_size: [1400, 1400]
  self.use_transactional_tests = false

  def setup
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  def teardown
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end

  def uri(path)
    URI::HTTP.build(host: 'localhost', port: FRONT_END_PORT, path: path)
  end
end

unless ENV.key?('NO_WEBPACK')
  system(
    {'NODE_ENV' => 'test'},
    './node_modules/.bin/webpack', '--config', 'config/webpack/test.js', '--hide-modules') \
    or abort
end

if FRONT_END == 'separate_process'
  front_srv = ChildProcess.build(
    'bundle', 'exec', 'test/front-end-server.rb',
    '-f', FRONT_END_PORT.to_s,
    '-b', Capybara.server_port.to_s
  )
  if ENV.key?('FRONT_END_LOG')
    front_srv.io.inherit!
  end
  front_srv.start
  Minitest.after_run {
    front_srv.stop
  }
else
  Thread.new do
    FrontEndServer.new({
      Port: FRONT_END_PORT,
      back_end_port: Capybara.server_port,
      Logger: Rails.logger,
    }).start
  end
end

unless Capybara.run_server
  back_srv = ChildProcess.build(
    'bin/rails', 'server',
    '-P', 'tmp/pids/server-test.pid',   # to not conflict with dev instance
    '-p', Capybara.server_port.to_s
  )
  back_srv.start

  # wait for server to start
  begin
    socket = TCPSocket.new 'localhost', Capybara.server_port
  rescue Errno::ECONNREFUSED
    retry
  end
  socket.close

  Minitest.after_run {
    back_srv.stop
  }
end
```

`test/front-end-server.rb`:

```rb
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'webrick'
require 'httparty'
require 'uri'

class FrontEndServer < WEBrick::HTTPServer
  class FallbackFileHandler < WEBrick::HTTPServlet::FileHandler
    def service(req, res)
      super
    rescue WEBrick::HTTPStatus::NotFound
      req.instance_variable_set('@path_info', '/index.html')
      super
    end
  end

  class ProxyHandler < WEBrick::HTTPServlet::AbstractServlet
    def do_GET(req, res)
      req.header.each do |k, v|
        @logger.debug("-> #{k}: #{v}");
      end
      @logger.debug("-> body: #{req.body}");

      uri2 = req.request_uri.dup
      uri2.port = @config[:back_end_port]
      res2 = HTTParty.send(req.request_method.downcase, uri2, {
        headers: Hash[req.header.map { |k, v| [k, v.join(', ')] }],
        body: req.body,
      })
      res.content_type = res2.headers['content-type']
      res.body = res2.body

      res2.headers.each do |k, v|
        @logger.debug("<- #{k}: #{v}");
      end
      if res.body
        body = res.body.length < 100 ? res.body : res.body[0,97] + '...'
        @logger.debug("<- body: #{req.body}");
      end
    end
    alias do_POST do_GET
    alias do_PATCH do_GET
    alias do_PUT do_GET
    alias do_DELETE do_GET
    alias do_MOVE do_GET
    alias do_COPY do_GET
    alias do_HEAD do_GET
    alias do_OPTIONS do_GET
    alias do_MKCOL do_GET
  end

  def initialize(config={}, default=WEBrick::Config::HTTP)
    config = {AccessLog: config[:Logger] ? [
      [config[:Logger], WEBrick::AccessLog::COMMON_LOG_FORMAT],
    ] : [
      [$stderr, WEBrick::AccessLog::COMMON_LOG_FORMAT],
    ]}.update(config)
    super
    if ENV.key?('FRONT_END_LOG_LEVEL')
      logger.level = WEBrick::BasicLog.const_get(ENV['FRONT_END_LOG_LEVEL'])
    end

    mount('/', FallbackFileHandler, 'public')
    mount('/api', ProxyHandler)
    mount('/uploads', ProxyHandler)
  end
end

if __FILE__ == $0
  require 'optparse'

  options = {}
  OptionParser.new do |opt|
    opt.on('-f', '--front-end-port PORT', OptionParser::DecimalInteger) { |o|
      options[:front_end_port] = o
    }
    opt.on('-b', '--back-end-port PORT', OptionParser::DecimalInteger) { |o|
      options[:back_end_port] = o
    }
  end.parse!

  server = FrontEndServer.new({
    Port: options[:front_end_port],
    back_end_port: options[:back_end_port],
  })
  trap('INT') { server.shutdown }
  trap('TERM') { server.shutdown }
  server.start
end
```

Tested with `rails-5.1.1`, `webpack-2.4.1`.

To run the tests you can use the following commands:

```
$ xvfb-run TESTOPTS=-h bin/rails test:system
$ xvfb-run bin/rails test -h test/system/application_test.rb:6
$ xvfb-run TEST=test/system/application_test.rb TESTOPTS=-h bin/rake test
```

You can simplify running tests by adding package scripts:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "xvfb-run bin/rails test:system",
  "test1": "xvfb-run bin/rails test"
}
```

Then:

```
$ yarn test
$ yarn test1 test/system/application_test.rb:6
```

Or so I'd like to say. But unfortunately `yarn` has an [issue](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/5935) where it prepends extra paths to the `PATH` variable. Particularly, `/usr/bin`. Which leads to system `ruby` being executed. With all sorts of outcomes (`ruby` not finding gems).

To work around it you may use the following script:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -eu

# https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/5935

s_path=$(printf "%s" "$PATH" | tr : \\n)
_IFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
a_path=($s_path)
IFS=$_IFS

usr_bin=$(dirname -- "$(which node)")
n_usr_bin=$(egrep "^$usr_bin$" <(printf "%s" "$s_path") | wc -l)
r=()
for (( i = 0; i < ${#a_path[@]}; i++ )); do
    if [ "${a_path[$i]}" = "$usr_bin" ] && (( n_usr_bin > 1 )); then
        (( n_usr_bin-- ))
    else
        r+=("${a_path[$i]}")
    fi
done

PATH=$(
    for p in ${r[@]+"${r[@]}"}; do
        printf "%s\n" "$p"
    done | paste -sd:
)

"$@"
```

Then the package scripts are to be read as follows:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "./fix-path.sh xvfb-run bin/rails test:system",
  "test1": "./fix-path.sh xvfb-run bin/rails test"
}
```

By default, `rails` starts `puma` in a separate thread to handle api requests while running tests. With this setup it by default runs in a separate process. Since then you can drop `byebug` line anywhere in your test, and the site in the browser will remain functional (XHR requests will not stuck). You can still make it run in a separate thread if you feel like it by setting `BACK_END=separate_thread`.

Additionally, another process (or thread, depending on the value of the `FRONT_END` variable) will start to handle requests for static files (or proxy requests to the back end). For that `webrick` is used.

To see `rails`'s output, run with `RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT=1`, or see `log/test.log`. To prevent `rails` from colorizing the log, add `config.colorize_logging = false` (which will strip colors in the console as well) to `config/environments/test.rb`, or use `less -R log/test.log`. `puma`'s output can be seen by running with `BACK_END_LOG=1`.

To see `webrick`'s output, run with `FRONT_END_LOG=1` (separate process), `RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT=1` (separate thread), or see `log/test.log` (separate thread). To make `webrick` produce more info, set `FRONT_END_LOG_LEVEL` to `DEBUG`.

Also, every time you run the tests, `webpack` starts to compile the bundle. You can avoid that with `WEBPACK=1`.

Finally, to see [Selenium requests](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/Logger.html):

```rb
Selenium::WebDriver.logger.level = :debug   # full logging
Selenium::WebDriver.logger.level = :warn   # back to normal
Selenium::WebDriver.logger.output = 'selenium.log'   # log to file
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://ruby-hyperloop.org. You can drive your client test suite from rspec, and easily integrate with rails

Comment: Um, I couldn't find explanation of how it works on the site. (Sorry for being blunt here.) I'm probably wrong, but it reminded me of ASP.NET. At any case, at first glance it looks like more trouble than it's worth. Leaky abstractions, and all. Probably geared towards people who don't like Javascript. Correct me if I'm wrong, please. And not at all what I asked. I'm concerned with testing front end that is separate from back end (no server-side rendering).